# Foundation Interchange not changing background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use Foundations Interchange plugin to change the background image on a div dependant on the screen size but I'm unable to figure out why it's not working correctly.

Foundation is initialised fine and when I resize the screen data-uuid is updated, but there is no background-image style.

I've created a jsfiddle to show you what I'm doing:

```
<div data-interchange="[image1.png, (large)],[image2.png, (medium)]"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rb90qq08/6/

This is exactly how it should be according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation doesn't say it explicitly, but you need to specify a default.

```
<div data-interchange="[image1.png, (default)],[image2.png, (medium)]"></div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckcj9fzy/).

Comment: When I add a default the div just vanishes, any ideas?